# php proxy woff font using fpassthru

Tags: php, fonts, proxy, http-headers

Hi I am trying to proxy a woff font file using PHP

this is the code I am using $path is the path to file on the harddisk. But I get an error in the console

**Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1
fakemboard.com/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag**

If I use PHPStorm default http server it works fine.

I have attached two images:

1) The first is the problematic response with my PHP proxy

2) the second one is the OK one using PHPStorm default server

Can you help me find out what is missing with my proxy? I believe it may be headers buy I am weak at that. So it will be really helpful if you provide the missing code. Thanks

```
header('content-type: application/font-woff');
$file =  fopen($path, 'rb');
if ($file) {
    fpassthru($file);
    exit;
}
```

[image: Error response from my proxy]

[image: Ok response from PHPStorm Server]

Comment: compare the byte response from both using cURL or something. It sounds like your proxy is modifying the actual font itself.

Answer (score 0):

I flowed Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans advice and compered the good file font file with the bad font file. Indeed they were different. The bad file has two extra blank lines in the beginning.

It happened because that in one of the PHP files that I have included I accidentally added blank lines before the `<?php` tag and php rendered them. Hope this helps someone else